# Read data from excel file using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Which is the better method to read data from an excel file?  OPENDATASOURCE or the OPENROWSET function?

I tried using openrowset but it is giving me errors:

> Ole db provider 'Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0' cannot be used for
>   distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in
>   single threaded apartment mode

Please advise!

Comment: Depends on the use case. If its a manual one time deal dump the data into a dump table using the import wizard. If its part of a process use ssis to dump the data. You can also use ado.net as well.

Comment: I plan to use TSQL to import the data from an excel file.  Is this possible?  I do not want to use SSIS.

Comment: Please provide your source code which uses `OPENROWSET`, so we can review if it is correct. Also, tell what operating system are you using on your computer - which one as well as 32 or 64 bit.